# Is there any geometric 'meaning' for line integrals in the complex plane?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration

We all know from ordinary calculus that an simple integral means to sum up a lot of pieces of area, double integrals a lot of pieces of volume, and so on (roughly speaking, of course).

I'm now studying line integrals on the complex plane, and i want to know if there is some kind of 'meaning' on them. I know what i am summing up, but i don't understand what the result means, for a finite line. Does the final result has a meaning? For example, if a line integral along a curve $C$ equals $z=a+bi$, what is the meaning of $z$?(if there is a meaning at all). Thanks.

Comment: Interpreting complex functions as a vector field in $\Bbb R^2$ (at each point in the plane, the function gives you a vector), you get some cool interpretations, like if it is a force field, then the integral is the work done to make a particle move along the path (by the way, in this interpretation, holomorphic translates to curl-free).

Comment: I like Arthur's comment, which can be turned into a nice answer. One can also think of it, though I am not sure if this is along what the OP had in mind, as providing a pairing between complex $1$-chains, and $1$-forms of type $(1,0)$ over the complex plane. This is giving me some ideas, because on the forms over a complex manifold, one has a bigrading. Does that bigrading correspond to something on the level of complex chains? If so what is it? I meant to write a comment, and ended up writing another question!

Comment: @Arthur, "in this interpretation, holomorphic translates to curl-free" could you explain this? I can understand it via Cauchy-Goursat theorem, but it doesn't seem clear to me that the idea of a differentiable complex function relate to a curl-free vector field.

Comment: @Dovah-king The Cauchy-Riemann equations become "curl = 0" when you translate. No trick to it, it's just a consequence of the renaming.

Comment: I can see it now, thanks.

Comment: Still waiting for a good answer. Might consider adding a bounty to it..

Comment: Even with a bounty, no answer came. That's odd.